# "How to concatenate data of two arrays and insert into mysql database?"

Tags: mysql, arrays, concatenation

I have two mysql queries to insert the data into two different tables.  the result of the queries are as follows:

1. `INSERT INTO table1 (ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5) VALUES (0,0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0)`
2. `INSERT INTO table2 (uid,cid,sid) VALUES (1,abc,123),(2,def,456),(3,ghi,789)`

How can I concatenate these two results so that the output would look like

```
INSERT INTO table3 (uid,cid,sid,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5)
VALUES
    (1,abc,123,0,0,0,0,0),
    (2,def,456,1,1,1,0,0),
    (3,ghi,789,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: There is no real way to do this.  You need to provide one or more join columns which relate a record in the first table to one or more records in the second table.  SQL is not like Excel, where you can just dump rows and columns willy-nilly.

Comment: If you want, you can create PHP code that inserts values into database and in PHP you can realize inserting value into 3rd table.

Comment: "_result_ of the queries"? or are they the queries themselves?

Comment: @Hackrrr, basically I do not know how to concatenate the two quires into third table. Could you please suggest the piece of code. I'm showing the out put of what is writing into database. "echo $myquery;"

Comment: As an aside, any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) alarm bells should start ringing. Your table design is likely not optimized for the kinds of queries you'd be likely to run against it.

Comment: On what basis are you planning to concatenate the data?

Answer (score 1):

I think something as this:

```
<?php
//First we need connect to database
$server = "localhost";
$Userdb = "admin";
$Passworddb = "password";
$database = "db";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $Userdb, $Passworddb, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

//Getting values - for this example it is static
//For concate we need values as array => explode()
$colums1 = "ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5";
$values1 = explode("),(", substr("(0,0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0)", 1, -1));
$colums2 = "uid,cid,sid";
$values2 = explode("),(", substr("(1,abc,123),(2,def,456),(3,ghi,789)", 1, -1));

//Query for table1
$command = "INSERT INTO table1 (".$colums1.") VALUES ".$values1;
mysqli_query($conn, $command) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

//Query for table2
$command = "INSERT INTO table2 (".$colums2.") VALUES ".$values2;
mysqli_query($conn, $command) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

//We need to concate values so =>
//=> For every index of $values1 add at same index into $values3 concated $values1 and $values2

$values3 = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($values1); $x++) { 
    $values3[$x] = "(".$values2[x].",".$values1[$x].")";
}

//Query for table3
$command = "INSERT INTO table3 (".$colums2.",".$colums1.") VALUES (".implode("),(", $values3).")";
mysqli_query($conn, $command) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

I think that this SHOULD works (one never knows :) )

Comment: Thank You so much @Hackrrr. You post helped me to insert the data into db table.